# how to access web service endpoint url without authentication from a oracle plsql procedure?

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, plsql, oracle11g

I have created a sample anonymous block which exposes a plsql procedure to get the employee details through the web service. We are obtaining the response properly , however we are able to access the endpoint url(http://localhost:8080/..) only if schema's username and password are provided in the url. How to access the url globally without any authentication?

we are using oracle 11g xdb server

End point url used in the code:
...

```
 l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request(url =>http://PERU_WS:1234@localhost:8088/orawsv/PERU_WS/GETEMP_DETAILS', method => 'POST',http_version => 'HTTP/1.1');
...
```

SOAP Request:

```
`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:get="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/PERU_WS/GETEMP_DETAILS"> <soapenv:Header/>  <soapenv:Body> <get:GETEMP_DETAILSInput> <get:P_OUT-VARCHAR2-OUT/> <get:P_ID-NUMBER-IN>'||P_ID||'</get:P_ID-NUMBER-IN> </get:GETEMP_DETAILSInput> </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>` (p_id=4)
```

SOAP Response:
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
Response> status_code: "200"
Response> reason_phrase: "OK"
Response> http_version: "HTTP/1.1"
Response> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GETEMP_DETAILSOutput xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/PERU_WS/GETEMP_DETAILS">
      <P_OUT>Manju</P_OUT>
    </GETEMP_DETAILSOutput>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```